# Trigger change event on individual option selected in `select` with `multiple` attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Given a standard select as per below, is is possible by jQuery (or otherwise) to trigger a change event on individual options - As multiple may be selected, I don't want to trigger on the `select` but on the `option`?

```
<select multiple="">
  <option>Test 2</option>
  <option>Testing 3</option>
</select>
```

Something like:

```
$(`option`).trigger(`change`);
```

Comment: `option` elements do support events, the `select` does.

Comment: No there is no change event for options.  I'm unclear what you might want to do if there were, by triggering it.

Comment: It is unclear why you need to trigger on an option. What is your actual problem?

Comment: @epascarello It's a super secret hack for a project that should use React but doesn't

Comment: Sounds like you are putting a bandaid on the actual problem. With more code and more details on the actual problem you are trying to solve would lead to a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to keep a reference of the last state of the multi-select, then compare to find the most recently clicked option.

```js
let sels = [];
$(`select`).on(`change`, function() {
  $(this).val().forEach(v => {
    if (sels.indexOf(v) === -1) {
      console.log(`The option most recently selected is ${v}`);
    }
  })
  sels = $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="">
  <option value='2'>Test 2</option>
  <option value='3'>Testing 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If this answered your question, consider accepting it as the solution

Comment: It doesn't on this occasion; I'm looking for a way to trigger a change event when the individual option is selected, for each option. I'll have to fall back to getting / setting the selected values with some logic wrapped around e.g., `$("#some-select").val(["Test", "Prof", "Off"]);`

Comment: I don't understand. Seems like you would need to determine which option was chosen, then run a block of code for that instance. My solution shows how to determine which was the latest chosen option in a multi-select element - whereby you would then trigger the custom code for that.

Comment: The options chosen are pre-determined (stored in DB). The front end needs to display which options are chosen previously when the page loads, and then show some further information on the basis that the individual option was chosen. So unless it can be (re)triggered when the page is revisited, the conditional extra content isn't loaded - But it would be triggered to load with a change event.

Answer (score 0):

There is no change on an option. If you want it to act like a user is selecting option by option in the select, you would need to select the option and trigger the change event on the select.

```js
const mySelect = document.querySelector("#mySelect");
mySelect.addEventListener("change", function () {
  const selected = Array.from(mySelect.querySelectorAll("option:checked")).map(x => x.value);
  console.log(selected);
});


function triggerEvent(elem, event){
  const evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  evt.initEvent(event, true, true );
  elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

const values = ['1','2','4'];
values.forEach(val => {
  const opt = mySelect.querySelector(`[value="${val}"]`);
  if (opt) {
    opt.selected = true;
    triggerEvent(mySelect, 'change');
  }
});


/*
const values = ['1','2','4'];
const options = mySelect.querySelectorAll("option");
options.forEach(opt => {
  const initial = opt.selected;
  opt.selected = values.includes(opt.value);
  if (opt.selected !== initial) {
    triggerEvent(mySelect, 'change');
  }
});
*/
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" multiple>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
  <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

The real solution is why is your page not set up to handle default values? Seems like you should just be able to call a method with the values and be done. Seems odd to rely on events.